# XHR error not caught

Tags: javascript, offline.js

I am having an issue where an XHR error is not properly caught. I am using the Offline.js library to do some checking.

The code the library is performing is:

```
Offline.checks.xhr = function() {
  var e, xhr;
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.offline = false;
  xhr.open(Offline.getOption('checks.xhr.type'), Offline.getOption('checks.xhr.url'), true);
  if (xhr.timeout != null) {
    xhr.timeout = Offline.getOption('checks.xhr.timeout');
  }
  checkXHR(xhr, Offline.markUp, Offline.markDown);
  try {
    xhr.send();
  } catch (_error) {
    e = _error;
    Offline.markDown();
  }
  return xhr;
};
```

[image: picture of the stacktrace]

I suspect the catch not really catching everything. What then happens is that some other requests/promises are aborted. That causes other side effects in my application.

Has anyone ever had something similar? Is this done correctly?

Comment: Where are the curly braces?  That `try {} catch() {}` doesn't look like the typical javascript exception handling.

Comment: @ryanyuyu looks like coffeescript. The tag is missing, though

Comment: Ah, not familiar with that preprocessor.  Perhaps it should be tagged as such?

Comment: Can you show us the whole code? Which error is thrown there? It looks like not `send` is throwing but some other method call, or possibly even an asynchronous one.

Comment: try catch is not going to work with promises/asynchronous calls... Code is done running by the time that error is thrown.

Comment: my bad, i added the full code as JS.

Comment: send doesn't actually return anything (i think), you would have to wrap a promise around it and resolve/reject the promise when you get the error back from the `onreadystatechanged` event

Comment: The errors from your screenshot don't seem to have anything to do with the posted code (do they?). What error do you *expect* to catch from the `send` call?

Comment: I think that's my problem. I don't really know who is actually causing the error. Apparently like you say they are not from xhr.send directly.